TMDb, tmdbv3api: find total movies by genre
I'm using the tmdbv3api package to extract movie info via the TMDb API. How can I write a script where I specify the genre type (drama, horror, action, etc.) and the script returns a count of all the movies belonging to that genre?

Do you have a MWE or the structure of your data ?

No, I don't have a structure of the data. I was relying on ChatGPT and Copilot to give me the appropriate Python scsript using the the tmdbv3api package, to give me the movie count. I think I should spend time with the TMDb API documentation to understand the data structure and how to access it.  Thanks for responding.
